# Allowing Null-values in Shape field in UPDM feature classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, esri-geodatabase, utility-and-pipeline-data-model

I am using Esri's Utility and Pipeline Data Model (UPDM) found [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/gas-and-pipeline-documents/updm-2019-edition/ta-p/921198) and need to add some records with Null-Geometries, that can be updated later when required. The allow null property for shape field is set to **No** as shown in figure below:

[image: Fields' properties]

However, when I try to set allow null values to **Yes** using ArcMap, it is giving following error:

[image]

Also, I have tried changing the properties in ArcGIS Pro, the shape field is locked as shown below:

[image]

I need to add rows with Null geometries.

Is there any way to have records with null geometries?

The feature class is empty.

Comment: Try open table, go to last record and enter new line(s). In arcpy same can be done by using insert cursor without shape field.

Comment: tried also using arcpy, it is giving error, cannot add null geometries.

Comment: Database can do this dumb things. Anyway if you are going to recalculate shape later, put some simple not null shape for now.

Comment: Shapefile doesn't support the notion of NULL at all. Shapes can be NIL (0-vertex geometry), but not NULL. That restriction impacts file and enterprise geodatabase design, though in the case of EGDB, NULL is *required* for geometry columns (but it's still not editable).

Comment: @Vince it is not a shapefile but a feature class.

Comment: Right, but the ArcObjects model is data-agnostic, and file geodatabase doesn't make a clear distinction between NULL and NIL either.

Answer (score 0):

I created shapefile (polyline) with a single feature in it:

[image]

and run:

```
iCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("SINGLE_FEATURE","ID")
for i in range(3):
    iCursor.insertRow((i,))
del iCursor
```

Output:

[image]

I repeated it on a copy of above shapefile saved in FGDB:
[image]

Output:

[image]

These proves my point from comment, that feature class can be populated with NULL
geometries. If attachments are present one might need to start editing session first.

Note: set environment to union of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

A solution either in ArcMap or Pro is to use the GUI to create an empty Featureclass but inheriting all the fields from the dataset then append the dataset into the empty Featureclass.

1. As @Vince says, a Null geometry can only be in a File GeoDatabase and not a shapefile so you need to create your empty FeatureClass there.
2. So using ArcGIS Pro as an example, simply right click on a file geodatabase in your catalog pane then select new > Featureclass.
3. On page 2 of 6 **import** your fields and then make sure the shape field is set to allow NULL. Complete the rest of the workflow to create an empty Featureclass.
4. Right click on your new featureclass and select load data to run the append tool and insert all your existing data.
5. You will now be able to add new rows to the attribute table without needing to create a geometry first.